# "/bin" not in PATH

Tags: terminal, path, tmux

I know this is a commonly asked question however every solution I have tried to date has not fixed anything. Until about a week ago, my `PATH` variable was clearly defined (and is clearly defined still for normal bash sessions) and I always could open `tmux` and run things through `intellij` without fail. Now every session causes me to have to re associate my PATH with the command `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"`
. I have tried editing multiple bash files, made sure my `/etc/environment` and `/etc/bash_completion` both have the same exact `PATH` defined (same as the one above), along with an assortment of blog reading and googling. I also have updated both my `.bashrc` and `.profile` with an export of the path. Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you for your time helping me with the issue.

Comment: In most implementations, if you have a `.bash_profile` then `.profile` will not be executed.  Clearly something was changed, you need to check your startup files, including `/etc/profile`, which could have changed.  See `man bash` INVOCATION.

Comment: @cdarke Thanks for the response. I know `.bash_profile` and `.profile` aren't both necessarily needed, I just wanted to cover it for full completion. After inspection of my `/etc/profile`, the PATH is defined as above as well, even after entering tmux. This is one of the reasons why this is confusing me so bad- nothing seems to be changing but I know it has to be between outside and inside of tmux.

Comment: Is `tmux` relevant to this issue?  That is, is `PATH` different in a normal command-line bash session?

Comment: Yes apologies I should have clarified (and will make edits to my original post) that the `PATH` issue only occurs when I am in `tmux` or when I am in `intellij`. My normal environment does not have any `PATH` issues

Comment: So it has nothing to do with `bash` then?  If that is the case, please remove the `bash` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else having this issue, this is what was happening for me and how I fixed it.

My `.bash_profile` had been redirected due to a deprecated package system I at one point used to use. This caused my `PATH` to point at my java home. This was causing the system to not initialize properly on each launch, stopping the `.bashrc` defined `PATH` from loading properly. All I did to fix this was edit my `.bash_profile` to point at the default `PATH` value: `export PATH = /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`

That fixed all of the issues and now my `tmux` windows load and work properly